# Python , my object claims to not have an access to a method

Tags: python, object, methods, call

I'm writing some Python code and have a class as follows

```
class GO:

    ##irrelevant code 
    def getCenter(self):
        xList = []
        yList = []

        # Put all the x and y coordinates from every GE
        # into separate lists
        for ge in self.GEList:
            for point in ge.pointList:
                xList.append(point[0])
                yList.append(point[1])

        # Return the point whose x and y values are halfway between
        # the left- and right-most points, and the top- and
        # bottom-most points.
       centerX = min(xList) + (max(xList) - min(xList)) / 2
       centerY = min(yList) + (max(yList) - min(yList)) / 2
       return (centerX, centerY)



    ###more irrelevant code
    def scale(self, factor):

        matrix = [[factor,0,0],[0,factor,0],[0,0,1]]
        for ge in self.GEList:
            fpt = []
            (Cx, Cy) = ge.getCenter()
            for pt in ge.pointList:
                newpt = [pt[0]-C[0],pt[1]-C[0],1]###OR USE TRANSLATE
                spt = matrixPointMultiply(matrix, newpt)
                finalpt = [spt[0]+C[0],spt[1]+C[0],1]
            fpt.append(finalpt)
        ge.pointList=fpt
        return
```

Whenever I run it it says: `AttributeError: circle instance has no attribute 'getCenter'`.
How do I get the object to correctly the call the function upon itself?
This is kind of a noobish question and I am learning, so detailed advice would be helpful.

Comment: You omit `self.GEList`, but it seems to be vital. (In any case, according to the error message, the object in question is not a `GO` instance.)

Comment: And how are you calling this code?

Comment: On another issue, a shorter way to split the GE into x,y lists is with zip.  For example, if `GE = [(2,3), (4,5), (6,7)]`, then after `[x,y]=zip(*GE)` we have `x=(2, 4, 6)` and `y=(3, 5, 7)`

Comment: Check the contents of `self.GEList` and make sure everything on it is correct. What line does the `AttributeError: circle instance has no attribute 'getCenter'` occur on?

Comment: self.GEList is a list of graphic elements whose centers I need to find.

Comment: I call my scale code when I have a graphic element that I want to make a different size.

Comment: The error occurs in the line (Cx, Cy) = ge.getCenter() and any, of course, the line where I first use the scale function.

Comment: Then, as I said earlier, check to make sure that `self.GEList` has the right kind of things in it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your indenting to make sure it's all consistent? That's a classic Python beginner problem. You need to use consistent whitespace (either tabs or spaces, most people prefer spaces) and the right amount of whitespace.

For example, this may look OK, but it won't do what you expect:

```
class Dummy(object):

  def foo(self):
    print "foo!"

    def bar(self):
      print "bar!"

d = Dummy()
d.bar()
```

This will return:

```
AttributeError: 'Dummy' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

If that's not it, try to pare your code down to the minimum, and post that and how you're calling it. As it stands, the general form looks OK to me, unless I'm missing something.